# iphone: Preserve view on top of mpMoviePlayerController

Tags: iphone, ipad, view, mpmovieplayercontroller

I have a mpMoviePlayerController, and I have subview on top of it. When the user taps the fullscreen button of the mpMoviePlayerController, the subview disappears, and only appears when I go back to the original size. Is there a way to keep the subview? Is there a way to get a reference of the "scaled" moviePlayer?

Comment: There is AFAIK no way of keeping a subview on top of the player in both modes (embedded and fullscreen). You can however add that subview in both modes as drafted in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick Draft:

- trap MPMoviePlayerWillEnterFullscreenNotification like this:

> [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
>   addObserver:self
>   selector:@selector(MPMoviePlayerDidEnterFullscreen:)
>   name:MPMoviePlayerDidEnterFullscreenNotification
>   object:nil];

- within MPMoviePlayerDidEnterFullscreen, add that subview onto the current keyWindow like this:

> [[[UIApplication sharedApplication]
>   keyWindow]
>   addSubview:mySpecialSubview]

Comment: this doesn't work for me on 4.2. Everytime I enter the notification method, the subview is not being shown. Then when I tried to get the array of windows NSArray *windows = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows]; the windows array has 1 object (it should be more then 1 as far as I know)

Comment: Alex1987, let me assure you, it does function perfectly fine across all iOS versions - i did implement it and used it in many apps. The point you made about multiple windows is not true anymore (since iOS 3.2 if I remember correctly).

Comment: this does only work for me the first time I go to fullscreen. If I switch back to embedded and then again back to fullscreen, the view isn't there anymore. Any ideas?

Comment: myell0w, are you sure the notifications are fired also when reentering fullscreen mode - maybe you unregistered from that notification prematurely?

Comment: yes, the notification gets fired. I listed to didEnterFullscreen, I also log the windows there and nothing changes in the window-hierarchy between the first time going fullscreen and the other times, but I only see my custom view there the first time I go to fullscreen. behaves the same on iOS 4.3 Simulator/Device and iOS 5 Simulator/Device.

Comment: Well, the basic idea does work, as mentioned before. There must by something wrong in your code.