# Adding an View on top of a MPMoviePlayer on iOS 8

Tags: ios8, fullscreen, mpmovieplayercontroller

I was using the technique mentioned on the answer bellow to add a view on top of a full screen movie. [iphone: Preserve view on top of mpMoviePlayerController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5479427/iphone-preserve-view-on-top-of-mpmovieplayercontroller)
Basically you simply add the view to the current shared application key window. Unfortunately this no longer works on iOS 8. The view is simply not shown. Any ideas?